# Is there an advantage to using 12V vs 5V for a powered USB hub design?

Tags: usb-hub

If you were to design a self-powered USB hub, is there any sort of advantage to a 12V design instead of 5V? The logic being that if the source voltage were to drop a few volts (maybe 2-3V), a 12V regulator could still supply 5V, making the system less susceptible to failure if power were to fluctuate.

Comment: Double the voltage, halve the current for the same power.

Comment: Why specifically 12V? Plenty of other voltages could be used too.

Comment: @justme Consider it greater than 5V for the sake of the discussion. Most hubs i've seen are 5V.

Comment: I'm just now realizing that whatever AC-DC power supply is being used for the hub should already be equipped to handle small fluctuations anyway.. I'm leaning towards no. Not much of an advantage at all over 5V. Just less efficient.

Comment: If the power supply is some distance away from the actual hub you might find it useful

Comment: @user253751 What if it's close by? Maybe 3 feet away?

Comment: "close by" depends on the wire size and amount of current. Perhaps using a 12V wall wart, and then converting it down to 5V in the hub, turns out cheaper when you analyze it carefully. Probably not for 3 feet of wire though.

Comment: If your hub supports USB-PD (you'd know because you designed it for that) you might want high amounts of power and higher voltages

Comment: "Why specifically 12V?" I guess for most of us 12V is the conventional "next step up" after 5V. You also see 9V supplies sometimes but they seem relatively unusual nowadays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For hubs with large numbers of ports, the current required at 5v would be impractically high and so higher voltage is usually required. These will usually integrate 1 or more buck converters to step down the voltage right where it is needed.

For this reason, 4 or 5 port hubs are usually 5V, 8-10 port hubs are often 12V, while industrial hubs with more than 20 ports that must supply several hundred watts are frequently 24V (thus avoiding the need to supply dozens of amps at 5v).  This way the total current on the plugs is kept to something reasonable and enormously thick copper cables are not required.

Answer (score 3):

Your nominally 5V supply may be slightly under-voltage, then you have volt drop in the power cables. Then volt drop in the protection circuit. The result is it may be difficult to guarantee conformance with the USB spec while using an external 5V supply.

Using an on-board regulator puts you in control of the voltage at the point of regulation and you can make allowances for volt drop from there. You can even use multiple regulators to provider closer regulation for a large number of ports.

Of course makers of cheap and nasty USB hubs don't care about any of that........